# Is it possible to expand Intel NUCs using many as a single computer? Will Windows also be able to handle it?

Tags: upgrade, gaming, expansion, intel

Is it possible to expand this and really use as a single computer? Will Windows handle it?

https://www.windowscentral.com/intel-nuc-gaming-pc

Comment: Yes and No. When it comes to networking, a task can be given to many computers in a network to speed up the process. An example is a rendering farm. But to turn all computers into one just is not possible because it would make the collection of computers slower than if you just had one because there's nothing as fast a communication on the motherboard itself, so all communication goes over slow channels.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to install Windows on an Intel NUC, as described in
[Operating System Installation for Intel NUC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005471/intel-nuc.html).

However, this will be a single computer. If you do this to several
Intel NUCs, then you will have several computers, each with its own
operating system.

You can't combine them all into one computer, no more than you can
combine several desktop PCs into one.